# How to check if two jQuery selectors have selected the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way for me to progamatically determine if two jQuery selectors have selected the same exact element?  I am trying to loop over a set of divs and skip one of them.  What I would like is something like this:

```
var $rows, $row, $row_to_skip;
$rows = $('.row-class')
$row_to_skip = $('#skipped_row')

$.each($rows, function (id, row) {
        $row = $(row);
        if (!$row == $row_to_skip) {
            // Do some stuff here.
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass jQuery objects into `.not()`:

```
$rows.not($row_to_skip).each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.is()`

```
if (!$row.is($row_to_skip)) {
            // Do some stuff here.
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the actual DOM element selected by jQuery:

```
var row_to_skip = $row_to_skip.get(0);
$.each($rows, function (id, row) {
    if (row !== row_to_skip) {
        // Do some stuff here.
    }
});
```

Two jQuery objects will always be different from each other, even if they select the same elements (just like two empty objects are different).

However in your case, instead of comparing inside the loop, it's cleaner to just remove the element from the set:

```
$('.row-class').not("#skipped_row").each(function() {
    // do stuff 
});
```